# Solving a simple system of ODE's

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I can't get Mathematica to solve the simple differential equation system below.  Could anyone please help?[

```
DSolveValue[{x'[t] == 2 x[t] + E^t y[t] - E^t, 
  y'[t] == 4 E^-t x[t] + y[t]}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

The solution should be sums of exponentials (for both x(t) and y(t)).

Comment: Please post your code as text, not pictures.

Comment: There are certain limitations to using DSolve, not every differential equation gets solved analytically using it. There are 2 things which you can do 1. Take a variable transformation such tat the equations can be written in a simpler form 2. If you have some initial conditions for the problem, try solving it numerically.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by @ Bruce Lee you may try the following. Let us represent `x(t)=u(t)*v(t)` and `y(t)=g(t)*w(t)` and substitute them into the equations:

```
eq1A=x'[t] == 2 x[t] + E^t y[t] - E^t /. x :> (u[#]*v[#] &) /. 
 y :> (g[#]*w[#] &)
eq2A=y'[t] == 4 E^-t x[t] + y[t] /. x :> (u[#]*v[#] &) /. 
 y :> (g[#]*w[#] &)

(*  v[t] Derivative[1][u][t] + u[t] Derivative[1][v][t] == -E^t + 
  2 u[t] v[t] + E^t g[t] w[t] 
w[t] Derivative[1][g][t] + g[t] Derivative[1][w][t] == 
 4 E^-t u[t] v[t] + g[t] w[t]    *)
```

Let us now choose `v(t)` and `w(t)` such that the terms `2 u[t] v[t]` in the first equation and `g[t] w[t]`in the second one vanish:

```
DSolve[ Derivative[1][v][t] == 2 v[t], v[t], t][[1, 1]] /. C[1] -> 1
DSolve[ Derivative[1][w][t] == w[t], w[t], t][[1, 1]] /. C[1] -> 1

(*  v[t] -> E^(2 t)  
    w[t] -> E^t       *)
```

and substitute this into the equations obtained during the previous step:

```
eq1B = Map[Divide[#, E^t] &, 
  w[t] Derivative[1][g][t] + g[t] Derivative[1][w][t] == 
      4 E^-t u[t] v[t] + g[t] w[t] /. w :> (E^# &) /. 
    v -> (E^(2 #) &) // Simplify]
eq2B = Map[Divide[#, E^t] &, 
  v[t] Derivative[1][u][t] + u[t] Derivative[1][v][t] == -E^t + 
       2 u[t] v[t] + E^t g[t] w[t] /. w :> (E^# &) /. 
    v -> (E^(2 #) &) // Simplify]

(*  4 u[t] == Derivative[1][g][t]
     E^t g[t] == 1 + E^t Derivative[1][u][t]   *)
```

Note that I in addition cancelled the common term `Exp[t]`. Now one can calculate the derivative of the equation 1B and substitute it into 2B:

```
eq1C = Solve[Map[D[#, t] &, eq1B], u'[t]][[1, 1]]

(*  Derivative[1][u][t] -> (g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]/4  *)
  (*  Derivative[1][u][t] -> (g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]/4  *)
```

Let us now substitute the result into eq2B:

```
 eq2C = eq2B /. eq1C

(*  E^t g[t] == 1 + 1/4 E^t (g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]  *)
```

The latter equation can be solved using `DSolve` :

```
DSolve[eq2C, g[t], t]

(*   {{g[t] -> (4 E^-t)/3 + E^(2 t) C[1] + E^(-2 t) C[2]}}   *)
```

Now one can go back and find the initial variables x and y. This is, however, already trivial.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be obtained without difficulty by observing that the substitution `x[t] -> z[t] E^t` immediately eliminates all exponentials from the two ODEs.

```
Unevaluated[{D[x[t], t] == 2 x[t] + E^t y[t] - E^t, 
    D[y[t], t] == 4 E^-t x[t] + y[t]}] /. x[t] -> z[t] E^t;
```

whereupon `DSolve` returns

```
Flatten@DSolve[%, {z[t], y[t]}, t] // Simplify

(* {y[t] -> 1/6 (8 + 3 E^-t (C[1] - 2 C[2]) + 3 E^(3 t) (C[1] + 2 C[2])),
    z[t] -> 1/12 E^-t (-4 E^t - 3 C[1] + 6 C[2] + 3 E^(4 t) (C[1] + 2 C[2]))} *)
```